# Можно ли использовать like any в jpaRepository?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Есть таблица из которой мне нужно выбрать записи, code которых начинается с определенных значений(для примера foo%, boo% и т.д). Таких значений может быть много.

Есть JpaRepository на сущность Test. Хочу составить запрос так, чтобы он возвращал лист id с подходящими кодами.

В postgres можно сделать так

```
select t.id from Test t where t.code like any(array['foo%', 'boo%'])
```

Мне требуется сделать подобный запрос в @Query.
Я пробовал так:

```
select t.id from Test t where t.code like any(array[:param])
```

где param это лист со значениями. Но он ругается:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: any near line 1, column 248
```

Буду рад любому пинку в нужную сторону

Answer (score 1):

в @Query(naviteQuery = true и можно писать прям sql запрос)